# How to know the order of the xslt operators?

Tags: xslt

System.Xml 'xsl:choose' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:call-template' element.

How do I know the  order of such operators in xslt ?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is a publically documented W3C standard so check the relevant documents, for XSLT 3 at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-call-template is saying e.g. `<!-- Content: xsl:with-param* -->` which explains the allowed content is a (possibly empty) sequence of `xsl:with-param`.

The spec also contains an XSD schema so any XML editor using that schema should assist you in showing the possible, allowed elements.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the spec, for quick reference, you might like the MulberryTech reference cards at http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/

Alternatively, there are some good books on XSLT ;-)

If you're trying to supply a parameter conditionally, then instead of

```
<xsl:call-template
   <xsl:choose
     <xsl:with-param
```

use

```
<xsl:call-template
  <xsl:with-param
    <xsl:choose
```